# Implementing Breadcrumbs on Sitecore

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc

I'm currently doing a Sitecore 8 MVC project that needs to have a breadcrumbs.

Currently I saw this website http://blog.ryanbailey.co.nz/2015/05/breadcrumbs-for-pages-in-sitecore.html. But It doesn't work for me yet because I don't know what to reference.

How to get every item in the path of my current page, if I can handle it already?

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should do it:

```
public ICollection<Item> GetBreadcrumbs(Item current, SiteContext site)
{
    Item homeItem = site.StartItem;

    List<Item> breadcrumbs = new List<Item>();

    while (current != null)
    {
        // You may want to add additional logic to opt in/out of 
        // the breadcrumb based on a template/field
        breadcrumbs.Add(current);

        if (current == homeItem)
            break;

        current = current.Parent;
    }

    breadcrumbs.Reverse();

    return breadcrumbs;
}
```

And then:

```
var breadcrumbs = GetBreadcrumbs(Context.Item, Context.Site);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can take the current item and then take all the ancestors of it.

```
var ancestors = currentItem.Axes.GetAncestors().ToList();
```

Then you can get home item and filter the ancestors to remove sitecore and content nodes.

```
ancestors = ancestors.SkipWhile(i => i.ID != home.Id.ToID()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void GetBreadcrumbs(Item ParentItem)
        {
            List<BredCrumbDetails> lstBreadCrumbs = new List<BredCrumbDetails>();
            string strcurrenttitle = ParentItem.Name;
            Item currentitem = ParentItem;
            int i = 0;
            while (currentitem != null)
            {
                var ItemTemplateid = currentitem.TemplateID.ToString();
                var FolderTemplateId = "{}";
                if (ItemTemplateid != FolderTemplateId) //here we are removing folders
                {
                    BredCrumbDetails bcDetails = new BredCrumbDetails();
                    if (i == 0)
                    {
                        bcDetails.BCPageLink = null;
                        bcDetails.Title = currentitem.Name;
                        bcDetails.IsVisible = true;
                        lstBreadCrumbs.Add(bcDetails);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        bcDetails.BCPageLink = currentitem.Paths.FullPath;
                        bcDetails.Title = currentitem.Name;
                        bcDetails.IsVisible = true;
                        lstBreadCrumbs.Add(bcDetails);

                    }
                    i++;
                    if (currentitem.Name == ("Home"))
                    {

                        break;
                    }
                    currentitem = currentitem.Parent;
                }
                else
                {
                    i++;
                    currentitem = currentitem.Parent;
                }
            }

            lstBreadCrumbs.Reverse();
            rptCrumbs.DataSource = lstBreadCrumbs;
            rptCrumbs.DataBind();

        }
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.